# NameError: name 'input' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, input

Não entendo o erro neste código...

```
def checkio(number):
    #Your code here
    #It's main function. Don't remove this function
    #It's using for auto-testing and must return a result for check.

    number = int(input("Escolha um numero: "))

    while number > 0 and number <= 1000:
        if number % 3 == 0:
            print ("Fizz")
        elif number % 5 == 0:
            print ("Buzz")
        elif number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
            print ("Fizz Buzz")
        else:
            print ("É um outro numero!")

    return str(number)

checkio(17)
```

Comment: Tem como por o código mais completo, eu acho que esta faltando chamar o `checkio`, mas não tem como saber como usou.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta executar assim:

```
python nome_do_seu_arquivo.py
```

Não sei se você está chamando o arquivo diretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve estar usando Python2 e não o 3, pra funcionar no Python2 deve usar `raw_input`

Troque isto:

```
number = int(input("Escolha um numero: "))
```

Por:

```
number = int(raw_input("Escolha um numero: "))
```

Se for migrar para o 3 então use o `input`